# Is there an equivalent of elem.innerHTML that gets the code in the tag body?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

If I have the following:

```
<p class="demo" id="first_p">
    This is the first paragraph in the page and it says stuff in it.
</p>
```

I could use

```
document.getElementById("first_p").innerHTML
```

to get

```
This is the first paragraph in the page and it says stuff in it.
```

But is there something simple you can run which would return as a string

```
class="demo" id="first_p"
```

I know I can iterate through all of the element's attributes to get each one individually but is there a function which returns `tagHTML` or something like that?

Comment: There isn't AFAIK, but why would you need to do this? What's the real-world use case?

Comment: document.getElementById("first_p").outerHTML.split(/[<>]/)[1] should do that given no invalid attribs.

Comment: @elclanrs I'm trying to convert HTML to a JavaScript array which I can send to a PHP page which saves the array and later loads it to reconstruct the HTML. I know that didn't really make sense but what I'm trying to do is convert HTML into a PHP manipulable data structure. And there's a reason I don't want to just save the raw HTML. Because I could just use `.innerHTML` on a tag surrounding everything I want to save to get the saveable content, but that's not really my intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is something of a mouthful: I wrote it as a one-liner, but I've broken it out into several lines here. But **this will get you a plain object where the keys are attribute names and the values are the values of the corresponding attributes**:

```
Array.prototype.reduce.call(
    document.getElementById('first_p').attributes,
    function (attributes, currentAttribute) {
        attributes[currentAttribute.name] = currentAttribute.value;
        return attributes;
    },
    {}
);
```

Going through this, `document.getElementById('first_p').attributes` gets you a NamedNodeMap of the element's attributes. A NamedNodeMap is not an Array, but `Array.prototype.reduce.call(...)` calls `Array.prototype.reduce` on the NamedNodeMap as if it were an Array. We can do this because NamedNodeMap is written so that it can be accessed like an array.

But we can't stop here. That NamedNodeMap that I mentioned is an array of Attr objects, rather than an object of name-value pairs. We need to convert it, which is where the other arguments to `Array.prototype.reduce` come into play.

When it's not being called in a strange way, `Array.prototype.reduce` takes two arguments. The second argument (which is third for us because of the way we called it) is an object that we want to build up. In our case, that's a brand-new bare object: the `{}` that you see at the end.

The first argument to `Array.prototype.reduce` (which, again, is second for us) is another function. That function will get called once for each item in the loop, but it takes two arguments. The *second* argument is the current loop item, which is easy to understand, but the first argument is a little wild. The *first* time we call that function, its first argument is the object we want to build up (i.e. the last argument to `Array.prototype.reduce`. Each time after that, the first argument is whatever that function returned the last time it was called. `Array.prototype.reduce` returns whatever the last call to its inner function returned.

So we start with an empty object. Then for every Attr in the element's attributes, we add something to the object, and return it. When the last call finishes, the object is finished, so we return that. And this is how we make the attribute list.

If you wanted the exact code in the tag, like a String, then I'm afraid there is no standard function to get that exactly. **But we can get a close approximation of that code**, with a similar setup:

```
Array.prototype.map.call(
    document.getElementById('first_p').attributes,
    function (currentAttribute) {
        return currentAttribute.name + '=' + JSON.stringify(currentAttribute.value);
    }
).join(' ');
```

The basic principle is the same: we take that NamedNodeMap and call an Array function on it, but this time we're using `map` instead of `reduce`. You can think of `map` as a special case of `reduce`: it always builds up an Array, with one element for every element that was in the original. Because of that, you don't even need to mention the object you're building up: the callback function only has one argument, and we just return the thing to put into the new Array. Once we're done, we have an Array of 'name="value"' strings, and then we just join that with ' '.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:-

```
      var attributes = '';
            for(var i=0; i<document.getElementById("first_p").attributes.length; i++){
                var attr = document.getElementById("first_p").attributes[i];
                attributes += attr.nodeName+"='"+attr.nodeValue+"' "
            }
            console.log(attributes);
```

Comment: That will provide the entire HTML of the element; he just wants the attributes.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Andy: how is it 'not an answer'? It is, or rather *was* (pre-edit), admittedly a *bad* answer but it was definitely an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. I've made some changes in the code now. You can check it.

Comment: @DavidThomas I see - he's updated his answer, I retract my comment

Answer (score 1):

It isn't a built-in property, but you can use the array-like object `attributes` to obtain what you're looking for.

```
Array.prototype.map.call(element.attributes, function (el) {
  return el.name + '="' + el.value + '"';
}).join(' ')
```

This is assuming a browser that supports the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function. The `Array.prototype.map.call` part is because `attributes` is not really an array and does not have a `join` method, but because it's an array-like JavaScript's dynamism allows us to call `map` on it anyway.

Example from the current page with the footer `div`:

```
var element = document.getElementById('footer')
Array.prototype.map.call(element.attributes, function (el) {
  return el.name + '="' + el.value + '"';
}).join(' ');
// "id="footer" class="categories""
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.getElementById("first_p").attributes` to get an array of all the attributes on that DOM element

If you wanted them all in one string just do: `document.getElementById("first_p").attributes.join(' ')` to get the desired output

Comment: `.attributes` is not an array; it is of type [`NamedNodeMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.attributes), so I don't think it actually has the `join` function.

Answer (score 0):

Well, while nothing currently exists to do this directly (though the approaches using the `Node`'s attributes is a more reliable approach, one option is to create this method yourself:

```
HTMLElement.prototype.tagHTML = function(){
    // we create a clone to avoid doing anything to the original:
    var clone = this.cloneNode(),
    // creating a regex, using new RegExp, in order to create it
    // dynamically, and inserting the node's tagName:
        re = new RegExp('<' + this.tagName + '\\s+','i'),
    // 'empty' variables for later:
        closure, str;

    // removing all the child-nodes of the clone (we only want the
    // contents of the Node's opening HTML tag, so remove everything else):
    while (clone.firstChild){
        clone.removeChild(clone.firstChild);
    }

    // we get the outerHTML of the Node as a string,
    // remove the opening '<' and the tagName and a following space,
    // using the above regular expression:
    str = clone.outerHTML.replace(re,'');

    // naively determining whether the element is void
    // (ends with '/>') or not (ends with '>'):
    closure = str.indexOf('/>') > -1 ? '/>' : '>';

    // we get the string of HTML from the beginning until the closing
    // string we assumed just now, and then trim any leading/trailing
    // white-space using trim(). And, of course, we return that string:
    return str.substring(0,str.indexOf(closure)).trim();
};

console.log(document.getElementById('test').tagHTML());
console.log(document.getElementById('demo').tagHTML());
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ydY9D/1/).